# Use different indexes for Solr searches on local dev environment

Tags: search, configuration

I'm using the [Search API Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module for search on my Pantheon site.  Pantheon's Solr module automatically sets the search index for the dev, staging, and live environments.

But now I want to install Solr locally and I want to use that index instead on my local dev environment.  I know I can change the environment settings in `settings.php`-- I have already done this for some things on my local environment.

I defined the **Server** for my local copy of Solr at
`admin/config/search/search_api`.  I have two different **Indexes** on this page, and these default to the Pantheon **Server**.  I can easily switch them to the local solr **Server**, but I don't want to do this every time I reset my dev environment.

What variable can I set to force the **Indexes** to use my local Solr **Server**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, Solr servers and their settings are not variables. They're not entities, nor anything else Drupal would know about, and subsequently be able to effect.

The settings for the server host/path are stored in a serialised PHP string in the search_api_server table. (the `options` column).

The best I think you'll be able to do is to add a step to your pull-from-pantheon process to run a script after the database has been updated. The script would perhaps delete all existing servers and add a new record with only the known good configuration for your local host.

Or you could have a module enabled locally only that checks for the host on each request, something like that. I don't think there's a way to do it without altering the database manually, or at least by using one of the API functions provided by search_api_solr.

Comment: Argh... in that case, I will use Selenium IDE to automatically click through the process of switching the indexes for me.

Comment: I feel your pain! I keep threatening to rewrite the config for this module so its environment-friendly but life keeps getting in the way